# Using print command Vs calling directly

Tags: python

I started learning about dictionaries in Python.

For the following dictionary:

```
nameMap={1: "Bob", 2: "Pete", 3: "Ben", 4: "Bud", 5:  "Russ"}
```

In order to obtain a value, the outputs are slightly different when using  `print(nameMap[1])` and `nameMap[1]`.

Can you explain what is exactly going here?

Comment: did you mean `Bob` and `'Bob'`? , the  later with ' ' means it's a string,if there was a integer it will have the same output, `print()` output string,so it does not need  ' ' to show it is a string

Comment: yes those were the two outputs. so what is the first one. would that also be a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is means:

`nameMap[1]` will return a `str` type object

`print(nameMap[1])` will return a `NoneType` object

**Here is the supporting code:**

When in confusion, use the `type()` method to check the type of a value.

```py
>>> nameMap = {1: "Bob", 2: "Pete", 3: "Ben", 4: "Bud", 5: "Russ"}

>>> nameMap[1]
'Bob'
>>> type(nameMap[1])
<class 'str'>

>>> print(nameMap[1])
Bob
>>> type(print(nameMap[1]))
Bob
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Answer (score 1):

> in order to obtain a value, the out puts are slightly different when using print(nameMap[1]) and nameMap[1]. Can you explain what is exactly going here. Thank you.

I think you mean the difference between "when you try to print the value of a variable using explicit `print` call" vs "without using `print` by typing the variable name directly over the interpreter".

I have tired your code with my interpreter:

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2019, 09:21:52) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> nameMap={1: "Bob", 2: "Pete", 3: "Ben", 4: "Bud", 5:  "Russ"}
>>> print(nameMap[1])
Bob
>>> nameMap[1]
'Bob'
>>>
```

My guess is that the difference in printing is due to the difference in the `__repr__` and `__str__` method of the class.

`print(variable)` equals to `print(str(variable))`

whereas

variable equals to `print(repr(variable))`.

Try this too:

```
>>> print(nameMap[1])
Bob
>>> nameMap[1]
'Bob'
>>> print(repr(nameMap[1]))
'Bob'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`print(nameMap[1])` just **prints** the value out on console (or whatever output system you're using).

`nameMap[1]` just **returns** the value contained by the dict, whatever the type is. In order to know what type the value is, `type(nameMap[1])`.